# Caption of subtable breaks into several lines

Tags: subcaption

I'm quite new in latex and have (at least for you) a maybe rather simple question, but i did not find anything that helped me after some research. I want to do a table with certain subtables, however my caption for the subtables breaks into several lines. I would prefer just one line above the table, position otherwise is fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Effects}
\begin{subtable}
\small
\caption{A subtable}
\label{tab:1a}
\begin{tabular}{l*{16}{c}}
\hline\hline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}\\
\hline
\# months    &       0.192\sym{*}  &       0.139         &       0.190\sym{*}  &       0.168         &      -0.019         &       0.070         &       0.065         &       0.139\sym{*}  &       0.185         &       0.072         &       0.018         &       0.047         &      -0.088         &       0.000         &     -17.812                 \\
            &      (1.65)         &      (1.28)         &      (1.71)         &      (1.13)         &     (-0.17)         &      (0.94)         &      (0.48)         &      (1.78)         &      (1.26)         &      (0.70)         &      (0.21)         &      (0.26)         &     (-0.86)         &         (.)         &     (-1.03)                \\
[1em]
\# quartals  &       0.557         &       0.406         &       0.525         &       0.485         &      -0.068         &       0.227         &       0.175         &       0.437\sym{*}  &       0.539         &       0.206         &       0.063         &       0.107         &      -0.244         &       0.000         &     -55.164             \\
            &      (1.63)         &      (1.25)         &      (1.58)         &      (1.09)         &     (-0.20)         &      (1.02)         &      (0.43)         &      (1.87)         &      (1.23)         &      (0.69)         &      (0.24)         &      (0.19)         &     (-0.80)         &         (.)         &     (-1.03)                \\
[1em]
\# years     &       2.508\sym{*}  &       1.999         &       2.282\sym{*}  &       2.556         &      -0.405         &       0.951         &       1.366         &       1.750\sym{*}  &       1.923         &       1.004         &       0.573         &       0.756         &      -1.194         &       0.000         &    -234.503              \\
            &      (1.85)         &      (1.54)         &      (1.68)         &      (1.45)         &     (-0.31)         &      (1.12)         &      (0.86)         &      (1.87)         &      (1.09)         &      (0.87)         &      (0.54)         &      (0.35)         &     (-0.95)         &         (.)         &     (-1.04)               \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\hfill

\begin{subtable}
\centering
\small
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1b}
\begin{tabular}{l*{16}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}\\
\hline
\# months    &       0.396\sym{*}  &      -0.017         &       0.008         &       0.197         &       0.056         &       0.032         &       0.202         &       0.131         &       0.461\sym{*}  &       0.174         &       0.299         &      -0.310         &       0.283         &       0.000         &       0.398\sym{*}       \\
            &      (1.83)         &     (-0.52)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.97)         &      (0.78)         &      (0.71)         &      (1.47)         &      (0.79)         &      (1.74)         &      (1.29)         &      (1.34)         &     (-1.15)         &      (1.06)         &         (.)         &      (1.78)               \\
[1em]
\# quartals  &       1.178\sym{*}  &      -0.057         &       0.018         &       0.593         &       0.172         &       0.098         &       0.610         &       0.400         &       1.329\sym{*}  &       0.490         &       0.918         &      -0.985         &       0.862         &       0.000         &       1.156\sym{*}          \\
            &      (1.82)         &     (-0.58)         &      (0.02)         &      (0.98)         &      (0.80)         &      (0.72)         &      (1.49)         &      (0.80)         &      (1.68)         &      (1.25)         &      (1.39)         &     (-1.22)         &      (1.08)         &         (.)         &      (1.78)             \\
[1em]
\# years     &       4.416\sym{*}  &      -0.317         &      -0.509         &       0.981         &       0.399         &       0.318         &       1.595         &       1.341         &       4.897         &       2.038         &       4.193         &      -4.298         &       3.354         &       0.000         &       4.519               \\
            &      (1.71)         &     (-0.83)         &     (-0.18)         &      (0.41)         &      (0.46)         &      (0.67)         &      (0.96)         &      (0.70)         &      (1.55)         &      (1.37)         &      (1.59)         &     (-1.36)         &      (1.04)         &         (.)         &      (1.64)               \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon trying to compile your document, you should get a bunch of error messages. Once you receive error messages, do not look at the resulting pdf file, but try to fix the errors first.

The first error message  you get is

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

This is because you forgot the argument of `\begin{subtable}{<width>}`.You could for example use `\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}`.

Additionally, `\sym` currently is undefined. I guess, the following line of code is missing in your preamble, so I added it:

```
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
```

With the above mentioned changes, your code now is compilable without error messages, but still throws some overfull box warnings since your tables are wider than the available space. I therfore added `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` and used `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{16}{c}}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{l*{16}{c}}` in order to make sure your tables are a) equally wide and b) fit into the available space.

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}



\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Effects}
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\small
\caption{A subtable}
\label{tab:1a}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{16}{c}}
\hline\hline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}\\
\hline
\# months    &       0.192\sym{*}  &       0.139         &       0.190\sym{*}  &       0.168         &      -0.019         &       0.070         &       0.065         &       0.139\sym{*}  &       0.185         &       0.072         &       0.018         &       0.047         &      -0.088         &       0.000         &     -17.812                 \\
            &      (1.65)         &      (1.28)         &      (1.71)         &      (1.13)         &     (-0.17)         &      (0.94)         &      (0.48)         &      (1.78)         &      (1.26)         &      (0.70)         &      (0.21)         &      (0.26)         &     (-0.86)         &         (.)         &     (-1.03)                \\
[1em]
\# quartals  &       0.557         &       0.406         &       0.525         &       0.485         &      -0.068         &       0.227         &       0.175         &       0.437\sym{*}  &       0.539         &       0.206         &       0.063         &       0.107         &      -0.244         &       0.000         &     -55.164             \\
            &      (1.63)         &      (1.25)         &      (1.58)         &      (1.09)         &     (-0.20)         &      (1.02)         &      (0.43)         &      (1.87)         &      (1.23)         &      (0.69)         &      (0.24)         &      (0.19)         &     (-0.80)         &         (.)         &     (-1.03)                \\
[1em]
\# years     &       2.508\sym{*}  &       1.999         &       2.282\sym{*}  &       2.556         &      -0.405         &       0.951         &       1.366         &       1.750\sym{*}  &       1.923         &       1.004         &       0.573         &       0.756         &      -1.194         &       0.000         &    -234.503              \\
            &      (1.85)         &      (1.54)         &      (1.68)         &      (1.45)         &     (-0.31)         &      (1.12)         &      (0.86)         &      (1.87)         &      (1.09)         &      (0.87)         &      (0.54)         &      (0.35)         &     (-0.95)         &         (.)         &     (-1.04)               \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\hfill

\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\small
\caption{A subtable}\label{tab:1b}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{16}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)}\\
\hline
\# months    &       0.396\sym{*}  &      -0.017         &       0.008         &       0.197         &       0.056         &       0.032         &       0.202         &       0.131         &       0.461\sym{*}  &       0.174         &       0.299         &      -0.310         &       0.283         &       0.000         &       0.398\sym{*}       \\
            &      (1.83)         &     (-0.52)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.97)         &      (0.78)         &      (0.71)         &      (1.47)         &      (0.79)         &      (1.74)         &      (1.29)         &      (1.34)         &     (-1.15)         &      (1.06)         &         (.)         &      (1.78)               \\
[1em]
\# quartals  &       1.178\sym{*}  &      -0.057         &       0.018         &       0.593         &       0.172         &       0.098         &       0.610         &       0.400         &       1.329\sym{*}  &       0.490         &       0.918         &      -0.985         &       0.862         &       0.000         &       1.156\sym{*}          \\
            &      (1.82)         &     (-0.58)         &      (0.02)         &      (0.98)         &      (0.80)         &      (0.72)         &      (1.49)         &      (0.80)         &      (1.68)         &      (1.25)         &      (1.39)         &     (-1.22)         &      (1.08)         &         (.)         &      (1.78)             \\
[1em]
\# years     &       4.416\sym{*}  &      -0.317         &      -0.509         &       0.981         &       0.399         &       0.318         &       1.595         &       1.341         &       4.897         &       2.038         &       4.193         &      -4.298         &       3.354         &       0.000         &       4.519               \\
            &      (1.71)         &     (-0.83)         &     (-0.18)         &      (0.41)         &      (0.46)         &      (0.67)         &      (0.96)         &      (0.70)         &      (1.55)         &      (1.37)         &      (1.59)         &     (-1.36)         &      (1.04)         &         (.)         &      (1.64)               \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: /Many thanks for your answer. What do I need to do if I'd like to have the subtitle left-aligned and not in the middle?

Comment: @Patrick: Adding `\captionsetup[subtable]{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false}` to the preamble of your document should to the trick.

Comment: @leandriss: Perfekt, worked! Many thanks!!!